# Why sometimes user name & SID will print at the first line while running at command line of Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, sid

Sometimes or some mechines, username and SID will print at the first line both of XP and win7.

**For example**, running `ping 192.168.1.1 -t`, print:

> *Tom SID:"S-1-5-21-2134784555-1762745530-142285977-1000"*
>
> *Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:*
>
> *Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64*
>
> *Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64*
>
> ...

---

I need to parse the output of command like `ideviceinfo.exe`(get iPhone info) in some other program.

But some machines will add user name & SID at the first line while running some commands, and some will not.

How can I turn it off or make it the same result?

Answer (score 2):

This is the first time I see username and SID in the `ping` command output. Looks like some third-party software is involved...

Things to check on the affected PCs:

- Does `Tom SID:"S-1-5-21-2134784555-1762745530-142285977-1000"` line, looks like `whoami /user` command output? Maybe someone wrapped `ping` in the batch file for logging purposes.
- What is the output of `where ping` command? It should be something like `C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE`.

Comment: Yes, just like whoami /user command output. 

I will try where ping later.

Thank you , and sorry for the delay.